# Tensorflow: differences on how to save a trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I noticed that in Python there exist several ways for saving a trained model
However I am not able to see the real difference between them.

1. Checkpoints

   ```
   saver = tf.train.Saver()
   saver.save(session, output_path)
   ```
2. Freezing

   ```
   from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

   input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
   output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
       session, input_graph_def, output_nodes_names)

   with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as output_graph_file:
       output_graph_file.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
   ```
3. SavedModelBuilder

   ```
   builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(output_path)
   builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
       session,
       [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
       clear_devices=True)

   builder.save()
   ```

Let's consider different scenarios: evaluation/inference, fine-tuning, serving API, export to other frameworks.
What's the best way for saving a model for each of these situtations? Are there rules about when to  use one method or the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an exhaustive answer, but with modern (mid 2018) TensorFlow, you probably only need Checkpoints and SavedModels.

As pointed out in

https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/checkpoints

```
"Checkpoints - a format dependent on the code that created the model"
"SavedModel - a format independent of the code that created the model"
```

"Freezing" largely got folded into and replaced by SavedModel.

In your training code and while you still want to retain the capability to continue training/fine-tuning, checkpoints are the way to go, as all the relevant code/state to not only train but also monitor that training is kept around between the checkpoints and your code.

When you move over to the "serving" side (i.e consumption), you add all the metadata needed to use the model, strip out the unneeded training elements and go to SavedModel.

I have not personally tried to export *to* other frameworks from TensorFlow, just into it, so I cannot offer a good opinion on what would be best for that case.